# Access "src" property in img tag from an Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create an Angular directive (attribute type) that, when set up in a img tag, is used to replace the current src by a placeholder (i.e: a loading spinner), and when the image is correctly loaded, put it back again in the src property to properly show it.

This is the code I currently have:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[imgAsyncLoader]'
})
export class ImgAsyncLoader implements OnInit {


    imageSrc;
    element;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.element = el;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.imageSrc = this.element.nativeElement.src;
        console.log("original src: ", this.imageSrc)
        this.element.nativeElement.src = "assets/loading.gif";
    }

    // Trigger when image has been correctly loaded
    @HostListener('load') load() {
        console.log("img loaded")
        this.element.src = this.imageSrc;
    }
}
```

1. The directive inits the ngOnInit hook, and saves the incoming src in the "imageSrc" variable.
2. Set the loading spinner gif in the src while the initial src is being loaded.
3. When the "load" event is fired, set back the src to the original one.

I'm not sure if this approach works because I don't know if changing the src in the ngOnInit hook will cancel the original asset load, but before digging deeper into that, there is another problem that I must address: the console.log at ngOnInit that tries to extract the image's src, is not working. Also, the "setAttribute" method is not correctly setting the new source.
 It shows "undefined" all the time.

Why can't I access the "src" property of the nativeElement? Is there any sort of limitation of Angular here, or I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you!

EDIT:

After using the selected answer (thank you!), I found some problems with how I was implementing this functionality: it's slow, it handles too much event listeners, and it causes many problems to both styling and performance. This way works much, much better in all cases, so I really recommend to remove the @HostListener and just implement the following:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.imageSrc = this.element.nativeElement.src
    this.element.nativeElement.src = "assets/loading-50px.svg";
    fetch(this.imageSrc).then(r => 
        this.element.nativeElement.src = this.imageSrc
    );
}
```

Works fantasticly!

Comment: Can you try `ngAfterViewInit` (with `implements AfterViewInit`) instead of ngOnInit? ngAfterViewInit should make sure that your elementRef already exists

Comment: Good one, this worked! I also changed the setAttribute way for just accesing the .src property in the nativeElement. Now with these changes, everything seems to work fine! Put this as an answer and I vote it as valid, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ngAfterViewInit` (together with `implements AfterViewInit`) instead of `ngOnInit`.

This will make sure that your ElementRef already exists.